# Change the class of div, after search on ng-repeat from text box

Tags: angularjs

I need to highlight the div of searched item. what ever the item searched the class will change to the particular div.

note: not the text

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="mod">


<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: mod" ng-class="highlight">

     {{item}}

</div>
```

Can anyone suggest me a way to this thanks in advance

Comment: Pankaj Parkar.. pls see my question not to highlight the text it is about div class of searched element

Comment: See my answer below i think hope it helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="mod">


    <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: mod" ng-class="{highlight:mod}">

         {{item}}

    </div>
```

Comment: It is highlighting every div in the ng-repeat

Comment: THanks Amit Ramoliya